React bundle size increased by more than the file that it included
require(`./path/to/large_file`)

Without this file being required, the React app build bundle resulted in 36 MB.
With this file included, it resulted in 80 MB.
However, the size of the file itself, ./path/to/large_file, is only 21 MB, via this linux command:
du -sh ./path/to/large_file

21 + 36 = 57
80 - 57 = 23
Can someone explain what accounts for this additional 23 MB in size to the bundle?

Probably the file itself require(…)s further dependencies which now need to be resolved and included in the bundle.
